# Can I make a sub class of discord.client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, subclassing

I'm trying to program a discord bot with discord.py. I want to make a subclass of the discord.client class so I can add some attributes to the class. Unfortunately I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/laser/PycharmProjects/DiscordNut/main.py", line 5, in 
>       class Bot(client):
>   TypeError: module.**init**() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Here's my code:

```
from discord import client
import random as rand


class Bot(client):
    pass


    async def roll(self, *args):
        input = args[0]
        target = input.find('d')
        numDice = int(input[:target])
        diceSize = int(input[target + 1:])
        output = 0
        for i in range(numDice):
            output += rand.randint(1, diceSize)

        await self.send_message(self.get_channel("505154560726269953"), "You rolled a: " + str(output))


def parse(content, delimeter):
    target = content.find(delimeter)
    if content.find("\"") == 0:
        content = content[1:]
        target = content.find("\"")
    if target == 0:
        return parse(content[1:], delimeter)
    elif target < 0:
        return [content]
    else:
        parsed = []
        parsed.append(content[:target])
        return parsed + parse(content[target + 1:], delimeter)


client = Bot()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    client.users = [i for i in client.get_all_memebers()]
    print(client.users)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    parsed = None
    if message.startswith('!'):
        parsed = parse(message.content[1:], " ")
    if parsed[0] in client.commands:
        args = [i for i in parsed if i != parsed[0]]
        client.commands[parsed[0]](args)


client.run("<TOKEN>")
```

Comment: `from discord import Client` note the uppercase `C`.  I'm not sure why this has to be a subclass though, it could just be a coroutine.